# Function without name

Tags: c++, function, function-pointers

I would like to know how to call this function? And where can i find it's implementation if it doesn't have name?

```
extern void (*_malloc_message)(const char* p1, const char* p2, const char* p3, const char* p4);
```

Comment: This is a pointer on function...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It isn't a function. It's a declaration saying that `_malloc_message` is a pointer to a function, with return type `void` and the parameters as given.

In order to use it, you'd have to assign to it the *address* of a function with that arity, return type, and parameter types.

Then you'd use `_malloc_message` as if it were a function.

Comment: What if there would be two functions which return type void and the parameters given?

Comment: Well you'd hope that `_malloc_message` would point to one of them, depending on conditions apparent by inspecting the program.

Answer (score 3):

`_malloc_message` is a function pointer.

Somewhere in the code you will find the definition of a function whose prototype is like this:

`void foo (const char* p1, const char* p2, const char* p3, const char* p4);`

Then you assign the function to the function pointer like this:.

`_malloc_message = foo;`

and call it like this:

`(*_malloc_message)(p1, p2, p3, p4);`

The question is why you cannot call foo directly.
One reason is that you know that foo needs to be called only at runtime.

Comment: It is not my code. I'm trying to learn advanced C++ by reading somebody else code. There are all those steps except a calling one. That is interesting, maybe the function is no longer used in that code and author forgot to delete it.

Comment: @Chyu • there are several good books on learning advanced C++.  Here is a curated list of books:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: @Chyu The call might be hidden in a macro. Also, since it's declared `extern`, it might be called from a different compilation unit.

Answer (score 1):

_malloc_message is defined in malloc.c of jemalloc:

This is how you may use it:

```
extern void malloc_error_logger(const char *p1, const char *p2, const char *p3, const char *p4)
{
    syslog(LOG_ERR, "malloc error: %s %s %s %s", p1, p2, p3, p4);
}

//extern
_malloc_message = malloc_error_logger;
```

`malloc_error_logger()` would be called on various malloc library errors. malloc.c has more details.